# Apple Music on Ubuntu

Tags: music, apple, music-player

How can I use Apple Music on Ubuntu, if its possible? Im thinking about switching over from spotify, but Im not sure if its worth it if I cant access the music from my desktop. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple Music uses iTunes, you could try using wine/crossover to run it on Ubuntu. The problem is that iTunes has been very hard to run on Ubuntu. You can check the status of iTunes running on wine [here](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1347). You can see that version 12.x (the latest) can be installed but nothing related to networking works. So if you already have music on your computer it will play it, but won't stream anything.

I do not recommend switching from Spotify to Apple Music if you're using Ubuntu. Stick to Spotify or try Google Play Music where both have a working web interface and Spotify has a dedicated app for Linux.
If Apple ever offers a browser-based solution to iTunes maybe it'll be possible but I really doubt it. Apple's goal is to get you into their ecosystem and close all exit doors so you depend on them 100%.

Comment: Spotify's "dedicated app" is actually just a Chromium wrapper around the webapp. It's better to just use the webapp so you're not running two browsers at the same time.

Answer (score 8):

EDIT 2019: Now it's much more easy to use **Web Apple Music Players** (see answers below)

---

EDIT 2018: I've installed it and it works (Ubuntu 16.04 and wine 2.16).

## Install iTunes with Apple Music on Ubuntu :

1. Download iTunes 32-bits (Apple Music require a version >= 12.3) : https://secure-appldnld.apple.com/itunes12/031-24468-20150916-D642FEDC-5C68-11E5-8BC9-CC5C6DA99CB1/iTunesSetup.exe (source : https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7270928?start=0&tstart=0)
2. Follow iTunes setup installation (https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=31322) :

> Installation:
>
> 1) Setup wineprefix with WINEARCH=win32
>
> 2) Leave configuration in Windows XP (for now)
>
> 3) Install with winetricks: gdiplus, msls31 ie8, ie8_kb2936068 .
>
> - If your winetricks is not able to install msls31 because of hash mismatch, just download .dll (it should be around 157 kilobytes) from any website (like filewatcher) and replace the existing one in windows/system32.
> - ie8_kb2936068 is not necessary but it seems iTunes Store is not crashing every time with it.

*I was not able to install ie8_kb2936068, it works well without.*

> - I do not recommend touching IE after installation at all, iTunes Store doesn't seem to work properly after that.
>
> 4) After you've finished installing components, switch to Windows 7 and run the installer. Make use it's 32-bit.

Then run iTunes (you can find it on your dash now) and it should work =)

---

ORIGINAL 2017: Update, it is now supported : https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=31322

Comment: It would be nice if you could format this answer less cryptically... and the fact that it's listed in WineHQ with a Bronze rating probably isn't exactly the same as its being "supported"

Comment: I haven't tried it yet but they said "What works : ... , Apple Music, ...".

Comment: Logging in didn't work until I installed the latest version of iTunes. "iTunes 12.7.3 for Windows 7 or later" from https://secure-appldnld.apple.com/itunes12/091-45190-20180123-72201368-FFEA-11E7-9647-F02911B39B62/iTunesSetup.exe. It says it's 32-bit. "Download now (32-bit)" so apparently the 12.1.x is not the latest 32-bit version but I think it's rather the latest Windows XP version?

Answer (score 6):

Apple does currently not have a dedicated desktop program for Ubuntu. However, they provode an API thru theirs MusicKit JS (https://developer.apple.com/musickit/).

Developers has used the MusicKit JS in order to create a third party web player. Here are some third-part web players that redirect you to Apples' website in order to authenticate yourself so that you don't need to give away your password:

https://playapplemusic.com/

https://music.zacharyseguin.ca/

https://am.netlify.com/

They are open source and source code can be found on GitHub:

https://github.com/naveedgol/apple-music-web-player

https://github.com/zachomedia/apple-music-webplayer

https://github.com/bottleneckco/am

Comment: https://playapplemusic.com/ and https://am.netlify.com/ are broken and I could not login to my Apple account on https://music.zacharyseguin.ca/ as of today.

Answer (score 4):

you could use the web app at [music.apple.com](https://music.apple.com)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way, No need to install wine or any application. You can use the web player for AppleMusic

https://tools.applemusic.com/en-us?country=us&media=all

https://itunes.apple.com/in/

Please sign in to your apple account else you can only hear the preview.

Comment: This is the best answer by FAR!  Just playing it on the actual Apple website, no third party apps/tools...

Comment: There is no need to install any application for you to listen to your Apple Music library in Linux.

The only thing you need is a browser.

https://music.apple.com/

follow the above link to listen to apple music in the browser, it looks and performs solid. Disadvantage: can't see the smart playlist in this web view. Advantage: don't need to depend on third-party apps.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice Apple Music web player by using the new, official MusicKitJS API.

https://musi.sh/

I found this is the best way to listen Apple Music on Linux so far!

Answer (score 0):

Using apple music page in chrome works (but misbehaves when paused and waiting) but has the same problem as [musi.sh](https://musi.sh); that is: favorite music list ("Songs") does not load completely and random play is very limited, unless, you take a lot of time to go to the end of the list.

Searching for alternatives I found this:

https://snapcraft.io/install/apple-music-for-linux/ubuntu#install

Does not crash much as browsing in chrome, but has same favorites' problem. In addition, every time you open it, it misbehaves and you must log out and in.

A somewhat good workaround for the favorites loading problem is to connect an Android device to computer using [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/blob/master/doc/linux.md) "latest" version, and just use the app with the device mirrored screen in your PC.

Answer (score 0):

[image: This is how apple music web looks like]

There is no need to install any application for you to listen to your **Apple Music** library in Linux.

The only thing you need is a browser.

https://music.apple.com/

follow the above link to listen to apple music in the browser, it looks and performs solid.
Disadvantage: can't see the smart playlist in this web view.
Advantage:  don't need to depend on third-party apps.